# Difference between getPreferenceScreen().findPreference vs findPreference

Tags: java, android

When I check guides for SharedPreferences for settings, I find that they use both:
`getPreferenceScreen().findPreference()`
and
`findPreference()`

Like in the following block:

```
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    Preference pref1 = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_test");
    Preference pref2 = findPreference("pref_test2");
}
```

Is there any difference between them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make no mistake, there are 2 different methods:

- [getPreferenceScreen()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment#getPreferenceScreen())
- [findPreference()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence))

Knowing this, getPreferenceScreen() Added in API level 11, gets the root of the preference hierarchy showing a snippet.

And findPreference() Added in API level 11 finds a Preference based on a key.

Both are deprecated in Android level 28 API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though, I still do not get it. What is the difference in terms of usage?

Comment: Do you want to read and save data in Android SharedPreferences?

Comment: I want to monitor the changes on preferences elements and hide some preferences elements based on some values from the settings menu. I can do it with both of the options. That is why I am confused.

Comment: You can read the data in SharedPrederences as follows.

https://pastebin.com/7k3zNQgr

And with those data you can perform some specific task that you need. You can learn more in the following Android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences